# Javascript validation not being executed when form submitted

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have javascript that is trying to validate a form, more specifically the "type=date" part of the form. But for some reason when I submit the form it doesn't even run the script (I think?) and just goes to the page specified in

here is the code

```
<!-- script to make sure only weekdays are selected -->
<script>
var date = document.querySelector('[type=date]');

function noWeekends(e){

    var day = new Date( e.target.value ).getUTCDay();

    // Days in JS range from 0-6 where 0 is Sunday and 6 is Saturday

    if( day == 0 || day == 6 ){
        e.target.setCustomValidity('Please select a weekday.');
        return false;
    } else {
        e.target.setCustomValidity('');
    }
}
date.addEventListener('input',noWeekends);
</script>
<!--============================================================
=======================form starts here=========================-->

<form action="confirm_booking.php" onsubmit="noWeekends()" method='post'> 
<?php
echo "Room: ";
select_room();
?>
week starting: <input type=date name='WeekStart'/>

<input type="submit" value="Book Room">
</form>
```

Comment: Also I'm not sure if this matters, but in the <form> tag I put "NoWeekends()" for onsubmit, instead of "NoWeekends(e)". Neither one worked

Comment: Nothing is preventing the form from submitting, the return false in the function is too late

Comment: guess you do not need (and not want) to run the validation on submit, but before. And IMHO date.addEventListener('input',noWeekends); cannot work, what about date.addEventListener('keyup',noWeekends); ?

Comment: Multiple issues: 1. the return value of `noWeekends()` is not returned to the onsubmit event therefore the form will always submit. 2. there is no event object available in inline event handlers. 3. you're trying to use the same function to handle the input event on the date input, and also the form submit event, so even if you had the event object, it will differ. 4. trying to assign the event handler to the date input before it is rendered (doesn't exist).

Comment: @adeneo i have little experience with javascript, or html in general. Could you explain where in fact I should be executing the return false? ddlab had suggested to run the function before submitting, perhaps this could help? How would I do so?

Comment: @mrcode I'm very poor at coding javascript (no experience at all) I took the code from this website: http://tiffanybbrown.com/2013/10/24/date-input-in-html5-restricting-dates-and-thought-for-working-around-limitations/ 

How would use the given function to validate before submitting a form? or is this impossible?

Comment: Why have you added an event listener if you are using an onsubmit ?

Comment: @rohan013 I copied the javascript from a website, I was unsure how to implement it into  my html code (no experience with javascript)

Comment: Finally understood where I had gone wrong, got rid of the onsubmit and let the event-listener do the work. Its working as it is meant to work. Thanks guys!

Comment: tested locally and works: 1. put the script part to the bottom of form part. 2. change the event listener from 'input' to 'change'. 3. change the var date from document.querySelector('[type=date]'); to document.getElementById('date'); and give the date field the id="date"... this works. the console.log(day) shows the actual day number. Best wishes

Comment: and wipe the onsubmit from form tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form" action="confirm_booking.php" method='post'> 
        <?php
        echo "Room: ";
        select_room();
        ?>
        week starting: <input id="date" type=date name='WeekStart'/>
        </form>
        <input type="submit" value="Book Room" onclick="noWeekends()">
        <script>
        function noWeekends(){
            var date = document.getElementById('date');
            var day = new Date( date.value ).getUTCDay();
            console.log(day);
            if( day == 0 || day == 6 ){
                date.setCustomValidity('Please select a weekday.');
                return false;
            } else {
                date.setCustomValidity('');
                document.getElementById("form").submit();
            }
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

works as expected

Note: The submit button is OUTSIDE of the form, and when clicked, the script is executed and submits the form programatically, if everything is right.